# What's the difference between the Gmail label buttons?

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels

I am sorting out my Gmail account, and started labeling emails, but I can't seem to figure out what the different icons mean in the labeling dropdown menu. There are 3 icons:

- empty
- minus
- checked

You can see them in the screenshot below:

[image: Screenshot of Gmail's label dropdown]

Comment: Great question! I did some minor changes: gmail => Gmail, and added ALT text to your screenshot. Hope that's OK!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you have multiple messages/conversations selected and you click the labels button there are three options for the list of labels presented:

- empty: none of the messages/conversations selected are using that label
- minus: some of the messages/conversations selected are using that label
- checked: all of the messages/conversations selected are using that label

If you only have one message/conversation selected then only empty and checked will be used.

Comment: That's a great explanation. Where did you find more information on this?

Comment: And how can I add a message to a label so that it will be gone from my inbox?

Comment: @Titulum Add a label to a message, then click archive. The archive button removes the inbox label. Or use the move button to do it in one step. Remember a message/conversation can have multiple labels.

Comment: @Titulum [Tri-state checkboxes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checkbox#Tri-state_checkbox) are fairly common for decades already, so most likely I assume Gmail will have no documentation specifically documenting this.

Comment: @Titulum yup this feature was in Windows for a very long time (maybe since XP?), not sure who invented it